# Spark SQL execute multiple commands as an ACID unit

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hive, acid

Is there a way to force multiple SQL commands to execute as a unit from pySpark ?
I'll have

```
Create table B;
Drop table A;
Rename table B as table A;
```

I would like them to execute as a unit. If something goes wrong such as B is not properly created, I would not want to drop A.

Answer (score 0):

Use try and catch with nesting. Then you can control things. But if the rename fails, what then? In that sense the ACID thing does not fly.